# Align text inside a rectangle.

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This may be a silly question...

I'm working with portfolio website. I need to align text inside a rectangle. I drew a box using rectangle tool. I can use my eye and align it vertical and horizontal, but I need to know the perfect way of doing this.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the layers you want to align in the Layers panel and with the Move Tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) active, use the align buttons in the top bar. You can also use the menu commands under *Layers → Align*.

[image]

You can read more here: [**Photoshop Help — Align and distribute layers**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/aligning-layers.html)